# screen freeze after calling presentScene with SKTransition

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm a beginner to swift and Spritekit here and I currently have two UIViewController: LevelSelectViewController and GameViewController. The latter is supposed to fire up different SKScene based on what button I click in LevelSelectViewController scene.

There are a UIbutton inside the LevelSelectViewController that when clicked would present the GameViewController, which would then fire up the AdditionScene.

Inside the AdditionScene there is a SKSpriteNode that, when clicked, refers to the GameViewController and call on its backToLevel method to go to LevelSelectViewController. When certain conditions are met the scene would also go load a new AdditionScene.

Normally the transition between view controllers and scenes are behaving as expected.

My problem is that, when I go back from LevelSelectViewController from GameViewController and then re-enter the GameViewController, the GameScene would not load the new scene when conditions are met and the screen would freeze at the current scene.

I checked and find that the new scene is initialized and loaded, but the screen is just simply stuck.

Moreover, if I omit the SKTransition in the presentScene method call the screen freeze problem is solved although it then has no transition animation.

Right now I have no idea what caused this bug and how to solve it, other than scrapping the SKTransition which is undesirable.

Here are the method for transition to GameViewController and telling it to load AdditionScene:

```
@IBAction func toAdditionLevel(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let viewController:GameViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController1") as! GameViewController
    viewController.gameType = "addition"
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is the method of jumping back to levelSelectController:

```
func backToLevel() {
    let viewController:LevelSelectController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "levelSelectController") as! LevelSelectController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is how I load up the AdditionScene in GameViewController:

```
            let scene = AdditionScene(size: skView.frame.size)
            scene.game_delegate = self
            scene.winningStreak = 0
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Here is the transition between AdditionScenes:

```
        let newScene = AdditionScene(size: self.size)
        newScene.game_delegate = self.game_delegate
        newScene.winningStreak = self.winningStreak!+1
        newScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        print("before presenting scene")
        let transition = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .right, duration: 1)
        transition.pausesOutgoingScene = true
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
```

If you just do 
            self.scene?.view?.presentScene(newScene)

There is no problem with screen freezing, but there is no animation for loading scenes.

Comment: transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false

Comment: Sadly that does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but setting the game delegate of the new scene to the one used for the old scene may lead to serious problems... Are you sure about what you are doing?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I think I am experiencing a similar issue and it's driving me crazy.